# Is there a way to precompile React jsx files in ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, reactjs.net

I have a page that uses React, where references the `System.Web.Optimization.React.BabelBundle` I created for all my ReactJS core files and jsx files.

My babel handler is `React.Web.BabelHandlerFactory`

My problem is the first time I load the page, it takes super long to fetch all the jsx files sequentially, so I believe it's actually compiling them one by one and look for dependencies.

Is there a way to precompile the jsx files so I don't need to suffer this first time loading wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out the script will be pre-compiled once I removed the `debug` flag in `web.config`.

`<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />`